# How to Display Product Details on CMS Page?

Tags: magento2, layout

I want to display product details (add to cart, media gallery, variations etc.) on a CMS page. I'm not sure if it's possible but I couldn't figure out how to do it. I've attached a sample screenshot to describe what I want to achieve.

Thanks in advance!

[image: Display Product Details]

Comment: No, this is not possible in admin side content or page builder edit section. You need to add a few customization codes for achieving your requirement.

Comment: Can I make with widget?

Comment: In Magento, there are no widgets available to display product details. You can create a custom widget type to display product details. The custom widget type may include the "product_content" and "product_id" parameters.